# how to show integral is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on a problem: Let $f: [a,b]\to R, a<b$, be Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$. Show that $$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\lim_{T\to b}\int_a^Tf(x)dx.$$

Letting $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$, I think this result is equivalent to the claim that $F(x)$ is continuous at the point $b$. But I think writing this as a solution may be too simple. But I do not have an idea on how to prove this result. Does anybody have any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: This is not a question of antiderivatives: The function $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$ does not need to be differentiable.

Comment: Yes, it's true. But the current problem is just to show $F(x)$ is continuous at $b$.

Comment: Which does not make this a question about antiderivatives. The function $f$ does not have to be a derivative of anything, regardless of the continuity of $F$.

Comment: Yes, we don't need to touch anti-derivative. There may(must) be some way to prove it directly.

Comment: A differentiable function must be continuous.  If this $F(x)$ is the antiderivative (on the interval), then it must be differentiable and thus continuous (_over this interval_)--but I'm guessing by some of the other comments that this reasoning won't do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So "differentiable implies continuous" is also true for boundary point right?(since most of the real analysis theorem often have the assumption like $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ , differentiable in $(a,b)$) Although I think from a lebesgue integration point of view this result is obvious, since integration in a null-set is zero.

Comment: Why not just compute $F(T + h) - F(T)$ and use the boundness of $f$ to complete the proof?

Comment: I'm not versed in real analysis, but if the function is continuous on the interval $(a, b)$ then doesn't that mean it's true that the limit exists at the end points (or is that basically what you just said)?

Comment: Yes, and that is what my question actually is--"how to prove Riemann integration is zero over a null-set, or just a 'limit zero length interval'"

Comment: So you mean your logic is "$F(x)$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$" implies "$F(x)$ continuous on $[a,b]$" implies $F(x)$ is continuous at b$, and done. Right?

Comment: Let $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Riemann integrable function such that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for all $x$. Then it is easy to show that $|F(x)-F(y)| \leq M |x-y|$ for every $x,y \in [a,b]$. Thus $F$ is Lipschitz. Recall that Lipschitz $\implies$ uniform continuity $\implies$ continuity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Amateur! BTW, is Riemann integrable function always bounded?

Comment: I was ignored...

Comment: @Nameless Yeah, I figured your statement was probably the proof.

Comment: @breezeintopl Remember how the definite Riemann integral on $[a,b]$ is defined via upper and lower Riemann integrals. These two concepts require the function to be bounded (so that the $\sup$ and $\inf$ be defined). So, yes.

Comment: No @Nameless, the comment "Yes, and that is what my question actually is bulabulabula" is for you :)

Comment: So...if we notice the boundedness of the function $f$, and then we can use any method we want. Such as, integral median value property to estimate(directly or by calculating $F(b)-F(b-h)$), or even definition of Riemann sum...

Comment: Thank you guys for answering my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something to get you started with.

Let $F(T) = \int_{a}^{T} f$. Notice that for $h > 0$ (if $h < 0$, flip things around), we have

$$F(T+h) - F(T) = \int_{T}^{T+h} f.$$

As $f$ is Riemann integrable, it must be bounded, that is for every $x \in[a,b]$

$$|f(x)| \leq M.$$

So this implies,

$$-Mh \leq F(T+h) - F(T)  \leq Mh \iff |F(T + h) - F(T) | \leq M|h|$$

From here you could do a bunch of things, but I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 1):

$$\displaystyle0\le|F(x)-F(b)|=\left|\int_x^bf(x)dx\right|\le\int_x^b|f(x)|dx$$

Note $\int_x^b|f(x)|dx$ is a monotone decreasing function on $[a,b]$ with infimum $0.$ So, $$\lim_{x\to b}\int_x^b|f(x)|dx=0.$$

Consequently by Squeeze theorem,$$\lim_{x\to b}|F(x)-F(b)|=0.$$

So $$\lim_{x\to b}F(x)=F(b).$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think my question is just why the inf is 0...

Comment: @breezeintopl: Take $x=b.$ Note $\int_x^bf(x)dx\ge0~\forall~x\in[a,b].$

Comment: @breezeintopl: Glad to help you.