# To prove that $\int_a^b f(x)dx =(b-a)f(c)$ for some $c\in [a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $$f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$$ be  continuous . Show  that  there  exists $c\in [a,b]$ s.t. $${{1}\over{b-a}}\int_a^b f(x)dx=f(c)$$

Trivially  it  holds  for  constant  functions . So  necessarily  consider  non-constant  functions . The  above  equation  looks somewhat  similar  to  the  MVT  equation :$${{\psi(b)-\psi(a)}\over {b-a}} =\psi'(c)$$
If  we  consider 
 $$\psi(t)=\int_a^t f(x)dx$$  and  prove  that  this  function  $\psi$ is  continuous  and  differentiable  then showing  $\psi' (c)=f(c)$  would  bring  the  result . This  was  my  idea ,. I  don't  know  though  if  any  of  it  is  possible at  all .

Will  this  tecnique  work  $?$

Thanks  for  your help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what you have to do.

Comment: $\psi(t)=\int_a^t f(x)dx$ is continuously differentiable if $f$ is.

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752545/prove-that-integral-of-continuous-function-is-continuously-differentiable
Might help.

Comment: That is the statement of the *First fundamental theorem of integral calculus*.

Comment: @Almentoe : Thanks .  That  is  exactly  what  I  needed .

Answer (score 3):

One need not invoke the MVT for differentiable functions (although that approach will work since $\int_0^xf(t)\,dt$ is differentiable for $f$ continuous).  Here, we work from properties of the integral and continuous functions only.

Since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ it attains both its minimum $m$ and its maximum $M$ there. Then, we know that

$$m(b-a)\le \int_a^bf(x)\,dx\le M(b-a)\implies m\le\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)\,dx\le M$$

Now, we also know that since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, that it attains all values between $m$ and $M$.  Thus, for any number $m\le y\le M$, there exists a number $c\in[a,b]$ such that $y=f(c)$.  Letting $y=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)\,dx$, there exists a number $c\in[a,b]$, such that

$$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=f(c)$$

where upon solving for $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx$ yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=f(c)(b-a)}$$

for some $c\in [a,b]$.