# Find a function $f$ over $\mathbb{R}$ that is $n$ times differentiable but $f^{(n)}$ is not continuous

Tags: calculus

> Let $n$ be a positive integer. Find a function $f$ over $\mathbb{R}$ that is $n$ times differentiable but $f^{(n)}$ is not continuous.

We know that all the derivatives $f',f'',...,f^{(n-1)}$ are all continuous, but how do we find a function where the last derivative is not continuous? The function we make up can't have absolute values obviously, so I was thinking it is going to have to be piecewise.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\sin(1/x) & x\neq 0\\ 0 & x=0\end{cases}$$ is once differentiable. The derivative exists for all $x$, but the derivative is not continuous. Try higher powers of $x$ to get a function that is more times differentiable.

Comment: How do you know the derivative exists for all $x$? What about $x = 0$?

Comment: Use the definition of the derivative together with the squeeze theorem.

Comment: How do you know that the derivative is not continuous?

Comment: The limit as $x\to 0$ of $f'(x)$ is not defined.

Comment: Also, does $n$-times differentiable mean that the function is differentiable everywhere for each $n$?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.

Comment: Okay, so I have the function $x^n \sin \frac{1}{x}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x = 0$ and need to show it is $n$-times differentiable. Is there an easy way to show that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37839/discussion-between-alex-s-and-user19405892).

Answer (score 2):

Consider 
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases} 
  x^2 \sin(1/x) &\mbox{if } x \neq 0 \\
0 & \mbox{if } x=0. 
\end{cases}
$$
This is a differentiable function with discontinuous derivative (see [Discontinuous derivative.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative/423279#423279)).
Then you can integrate $g$. (Check [Prove that integral of continuous function is continuously differentiable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752545/prove-that-integral-of-continuous-function-is-continuously-differentiable))

In other words you find $f$ such that $f^{(n-1)}=g$. So $f$ is $n$ times differentiable and $f^{(n)}=g'$ is discontinuous.